# Default Column "Title" not found in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am a newbie to Sharepoint. Now working on sharepoint online. But, when i create a custom List in Sharepoint online. I didn't get the default column "Title", instead i get the column named "Services". Other default columns such as "Created, Modified, Created By, Modified By" are getting while Custom List creation.

Can anyone suggest why this happens? Any related answers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Go check the site columns and check if someone changed the Title field to Services. If you are missing the Title field, then someone renamed it for all the fields in the site.

Comment: If you browse to your site's `Site settings` > `Site Content Types` > open `Item` part of the group `List Content Types`, do you see `Title` below the `Columns`?

Comment: @user19952 Yes, you are right. The Answer given by Jayakumar Kulkarni works. Someone renamed it. Thanks a lot to all for your timely help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List Setting-> click on some of columns not Modified and created,
then you see on the url at list you will find like "&Field=", that is original column name of that field by doing like that you can find title coumn.